# How to pause execution using guard and pry?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3.1, guard, pry

I have Rails 3.1.1 app with this guardfile:

```
guard 'bundler' do
  watch('Gemfile')
end

guard 'rails' do
  watch('Gemfile.lock')
  watch(%r{^(config|lib)/.*})
end
```

When my app is running under guard, a call to `binding.pry` does not pause execution. How do I make that happen?

Answer (score 3):

I haven't used Guard before but perhaps what you want are [Remote sessions](https://github.com/pry/pry/wiki/Remote-sessions)

Comment: There's also pry-remote which can be used with eg Pow, but that's a different scenario.

Answer (score -1):

This is from their GitHub page:

> pause: pause|p + return - Toggle files modification listening. Useful
>   when switching git branches.

Not sure if that's what you are needing.

Comment: This pauses execution manually, but how to get guard to break execution when it sees `binding.pry` in the code?